# formatting multi-row data into single row in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, reshape, tidyr

I am a strange excel or csv formatted file which I want to import to R as a data frame. The problem is that some columns have multiple rows for the records, for example, the data is as follow: There are three columns and two rows but the tools columns has multiple columns, is there a way I can format the data so I will have only record with multiple tools (like say tool1, tool2, etc)

```
Task             Location  Tools 
Raising ticket   Alabama   sharepoint
                           word
                           oracle
Changing ticket  Seattle   word 
                           oracle
```

Final output expected

```
Task             Location  Tools1   Tools2  Tools3
Raising ticket   Alabama   sharepoint   word    oracle
Changing ticket  Seattle   word         oracle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`. You can `fill` your dataframe so that Task and Location are included in each row.  Then `group_by` Task and `mutate` to add an id column for each task within each group.  Then use `spread` to spread the newly created id column across multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(Task = c("Raising ticket","","","Changing ticket",""), Location = c("Alabama","","","Seattle",""), Tools = c("sharepoint","word","oracle","word","oracle"))
df[df==""]  <- NA
df %>%
  fill(Task,Location) %>%
  group_by(Task) %>%
  mutate(id = paste0("Tools",row_number())) %>%
  spread(id, Tools)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups: Task [2]
#  Task            Location Tools1     Tools2 Tools3
#   <fct>           <fct>    <fct>      <fct>  <fct> 
# 1 Changing ticket Seattle  word       oracle <NA>  
# 2 Raising ticket  Alabama  sharepoint word   oracle
```