# R tidy a data set with record spread on multiple rows

Tags: r

I am importing data from a spreadsheet. There is one main row per record, and often one field flows over to the second or third row.

Simplified data looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(A = c("A", NA, NA, "B", "C", NA, "D", NA, NA),
               B = c("asdf", "adfg", "afgh", "BXC", "cxcv", "cqwer", "dert", "dty", "drty"))
```

> ```
> > df
>      A     B
> 1    A  asdf
> 2 <NA>  adfg
> 3 <NA>  afgh
> 4    B   BXC
> 5    C  cxcv
> 6 <NA> cqwer
> 7    D  dert
> 8 <NA>   dty
> 9 <NA>  drty
> ```

I want to get the data into a tidy format, with one row per record, which means combining (spreading?) the rolled over fields into their own columns.

This is my desired output:

```
desiredOutput<-data.frame(A = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                          B1 = c("asdf", "BXC", "cxcv", "dert"),
                          B2 = c("adfg", NA, "cqwer", "dty"),
                          B3 = c("afgh", NA, NA, "drty"))
```

> ```
> > desiredOutput
>   A   B1    B2   B3
> 1 A asdf  adfg afgh
> 2 B  BXC  <NA> <NA>
> 3 C cxcv cqwer <NA>
> 4 D dert   dty drty
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`. First, fill the 'group name' down so the rows that go together can by grouped.

```
> df%>%
+   fill(A)
```

> ```
>   A     B
> 1 A  asdf
> 2 A  adfg
> 3 A  afgh
> 4 B   BXC
> 5 C  cxcv
> 6 C cqwer
> 7 D  dert
> 8 D   dty
> 9 D  drty
> ```

Then, group on the group name (A).

```
> df%>%
+   fill(A)%>%
+   group_by(A)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 2
> # Groups:   A [4]
>   A     B    
>   <fct> <fct>
> 1 A     asdf 
> 2 A     adfg 
> 3 A     afgh 
> 4 B     BXC  
> 5 C     cxcv 
> 6 C     cqwer
> 7 D     dert 
> 8 D     dty  
> 9 D     drty
> ```

Next, add a row number (note, `row_number()` respects groups!).

```
> df%>%
+   fill(A)%>%
+   group_by(A)%>%
+   mutate(C = row_number())
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 3
> # Groups:   A [4]
>   A     B         C
>   <fct> <fct> <int>
> 1 A     asdf      1
> 2 A     adfg      2
> 3 A     afgh      3
> 4 B     BXC       1
> 5 C     cxcv      1
> 6 C     cqwer     2
> 7 D     dert      1
> 8 D     dty       2
> 9 D     drty      3
> ```

Finally, spread the resulting dataframe from rows to columns (based on the row_number, which becomes column number)

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%
  fill(A)%>%
  group_by(A)%>%
  mutate(C = row_number())%>%
  spread(C, B)
```

> ```
>   A     `1`   `2`   `3`  
>   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
> 1 A     asdf  adfg  afgh 
> 2 B     BXC   NA    NA   
> 3 C     cxcv  cqwer NA   
> 4 D     dert  dty   drty
> ```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Found this thread that solves the problem the same way - [formatting multi-row data into single row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442307/formatting-multi-row-data-into-single-row-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

One additional problem with importing from a spreadsheet, where one record's field rolls over to subsequent rows, is the `spread()` function wants records that are pivoting to contain all be identical fields, outside of the key and value.

For example, if I expand the original example to include a notional price field:

```
df<-data.frame(A = c("A", NA, NA, "B", "C", NA, "D", NA, NA),
               B = c("line1", "line2", "line3", "line1", "line1", "line2", "line1", "line2", "line3"),
               D = c(123, NA, NA, 234, 345, NA, 456, NA, NA),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

> ```
>      A     B   D
> 1    A line1 123
> 2 <NA> line2  NA
> 3 <NA> line3  NA
> 4    B line1 234
> 5    C line1 345
> 6 <NA> line2  NA
> 7    D line1 456
> 8 <NA> line2  NA
> 9 <NA> line3  NA
> ```

**Running the other code produces incorrect data!** Notice how line2 and line3 are not on the same row with line1!

```
df%>%
  fill(A)%>%
  group_by(A)%>%
  mutate(C = row_number())%>%
  spread(C, B)
```

> ```
>   A         D `1`   `2`   `3`  
>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 A       123 line1 NA    NA   
> 2 A        NA NA    line2 line3
> 3 B       234 line1 NA    NA   
> 4 C       345 line1 NA    NA   
> 5 C        NA NA    line2 NA   
> 6 D       456 line1 NA    NA   
> 7 D        NA NA    line2 line3
> ```

These incorrect result appears to be because `spread()` looks at the key and value fields, and requires the remaining fields to be identical.

To overcome this, `fill()` all the fields. I use `colnames(df)` to identify all fields, *this might not be the best approach*.

```
df%>%
  fill(colnames(df))%>%
  group_by(A)%>%
  mutate(C = row_number())%>%
  spread(C, B)
```

> ```
>   A         D `1`   `2`   `3`  
>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 A       123 line1 line2 line3
> 2 B       234 line1 NA    NA   
> 3 C       345 line1 line2 NA   
> 4 D       456 line1 line2 line3
> ```